# How do I combine these two Render Layers?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

How would I combine these two images without losing information?
I have tried the mix node, the alpha over node, and the z combine node, but can't get it to work. Hope someone can give me a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the word is 'node' :)

Second, Ensure you're rendering transparent layers for your leaf.
[image]

Third, the Viewer node is just a shortcut to see what the image looks like after a branch of other nodes have processed a node branch. To build both of these render layers into a finished picture you'll need a Composite node. The Viewer node just gives you the background under the node tree. You can use both: just feed both the Viewer and Composite nodes the same input.

[image]
Have fun :)

Comment: thank you very much, for the blender and grammar lesson =)